# UltraWinGrid scrolling to bottom with datatable

Tags: c#, datatable, infragistics, ultrawingrid

After getting a DataTable back from a stored procedure call, I'm adding empty rows to the datatable so the user can enter more data into it.  The issue is that after assigning the datatable to the ultragrid datasource property, the scrollbar moves all the way to the end.  The user will not be able to see the existing rows that were populate in the datatable by the stored procedure call.

Is there a way to have the active row as the first row or set the scroll bar to the top?

Here is the code:

```
dtRBMOverride = vprDataTable.LoadSP("rbmSelOverride", sqlParams.ToArray());
for (int i = 0; i < 99; i++)
{
    var row = dtRBMOverride.NewRow();
    dtRBMOverride.Rows.Add(row);
}
ultraGrid1.DataSource = dtRBMOverride;
```

This is what I have tried so far with no success:

```
ultraGrid1.Rows[0].Selected = true;
ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.RowScrollRegions[0].ScrollPosition = 0;
ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.RowScrollRegions[0].Scroll(RowScrollAction.Top);
ultraGrid1.ActiveRowScrollRegion.Scroll(RowScrollAction.Top);
this.ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.RowScrollRegions[0].FirstRow = this.ultraGrid1.ActiveRow.ParentRow;

private void ultraGrid1_InitializeLayout(object sender, InitializeLayoutEventArgs e)
{
    e.Layout.Override.AllowMultiCellOperations = Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.AllowMultiCellOperation.All;
    e.Layout.ScrollBounds = ScrollBounds.ScrollToFill;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to scroll a particular row to the top of WinGrid, you can set the FirstRow property of its RowScrollRegion to the desired row, like this:

```
this.ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.RowScrollRegions[0].FirstRow = this.ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Rows[YouRowIndex];
```

Check this article in their help for more information [Scrolling a Row into View](https://www.infragistics.com/help/winforms/wingrid-scrolling-a-row-into-view)

From your question its look like you need to scroll to the grid's active row. In this situation you may need to first set the active row to the one you need to scroll to. To set active row you may use code like this:

```
this.ultraGrid1.Rows[YouRowIndex].Activate();
```

One more thing. If your grid is in edit mode, e.g. user changes the value of a particular cell you should first exit the edit mode. To do so call [PerformAction](https://www.infragistics.com/help/winforms/infragistics.win.ultrawingrid~infragistics.win.ultrawingrid.ultragrid~performaction(ultragridaction)) method of the grid like this:

```
this.ultraGrid1.PerformAction( UltraGridAction.ExitEditMode );
```

Comment: I tried setting the FirstRow to Rows[0], but the scrollbar stays at the bottom of the grid where the asterisk for the bottom row is at. Also, I tried Rows[0].Activate, but the scrollbar remains at the bottom.  I tried both of the line codes after the DataSource is bound to the grid.  Should I put the line of code elsewhere?  My main objective is to move the scrollbar at top of the grip.

Comment: Having an asterisk means there was edit on the grid. Is your grid in edit mode? If so you will not be able to scroll it. Try to exit edit mode and scroll then. I updated my answer showing how to achieve this.